# how to copy all the dependencies of a Mave project and transfer to another development host?

Tags: maven

I want to work (remotely) on a maven project that I have no access to some of the maven repositories that the project is configured with (company local). I want a way to clone all necessary dependencies and transfer to my personal machine such that I can build the project without the company local repositories (I have SSH access to the project development host).

I know about Maven `dependency:copy-dependencies` but I want to merge these dependencies with my local `.m2` directory. in fact, what I want is to clone a minimum portion of a `.m2` directory that has all the dependencies of the project and then merge this to my local `.m2` and can compile and build the project. is this possible?

Comment: If you have an ssh access you can open a ssh tunnel to the dev machine and tunnel the repository access through that tunnel...

Comment: I can not. My SSH access is temporary.

Comment: I would just copy the whole `.m2/repository`. It is difficult to find out what you really need from that directory.

Comment: unfortunately the `.m2` is huge.

Comment: Then  use a new repository, build again that and then copy it.